# vcpkg: How do I submit a request for a package update, or see if the package is due an update?

Tags: c++, vcpkg

I am (obviously) new to vcpkg but I can't figure out how to either see if a package is due for on upgrade on vcpkg or submit a request for an upgrade on a package. I have seen how to specify an older version of a package in the docs but not request an upgrade, see the planed versions etc.

Any links and explanation please. Specifically at the moment I am looking at sqlite 3.35.5 and wondering if there is a plan for 3.36 (current) if not how to submit.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how vcpkg works, the maintainers of vcpkg do not manage package upgrades.  It is the responsibility of the package maintainers to create pull requests for vcpkg that upgrade their packages: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pulls

There isn't an [open PR for sqlite](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aopen%20sqlite), so either create one yourself or ask the sqlite maintainers to do so.